# Serialization of shared pointer causes error

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

When i try to serialize a shared_pointer using boost i get the following error.

```
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
    int main()
{   
    float val = 5.0;
    std::shared_ptr<float> p1 = std::make_shared<float>(val);
    {
        std::ofstream ofs("D://test.dat");
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
        // write class instance to archive
        oa  << p1;
    }
        while (!_kbhit())
        {

        }
        return 0;
}
```

This is the error.

Error   C2338   boost::serialization::tracking_level< T >::value != boost::serialization::track_never   PointerTest c:\boost_1_73_0\boost\serialization\shared_ptr.hpp  269

Comment: @AlanBirtles serialization of shared_ptr is supported by boost.

Comment: seems your error is somewhere else. can you post a complete example?

Comment: @Rick Pat This is the complete code in main function.